# Filtering Columns in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have this data frame (train) where I have 2314 variables and I want to drop the columns where the unique length of the column is < 2 and keep the columns where the length is > 1. Maybe I can apply to scale to my function and then run it!

Example:

```
length(unique(train$makeAcura))
[1] 2
```

And delete columns with length < 2

```
length(unique(train$makeAm.General))
[1] 1
```

Comment: `Filter(function(x) any(x>0), train)`

Comment: `select(train, where(~any(x>0)))`

Comment: I have used it but, it say's (! object 'x' not found)

Comment: @KU99 maybe it's a type. Just replace `x` with `.x`, i.e. `where(~ any(.x > 0))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Filter` to keep the columns where the unique length is > 1.

```
Filter(\(x) length(unique(x)) > 1, train)
#  a c
#1 1 1
#2 2 2
#3 3 1
```

Data:

```
train <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=1, c=c(1,2,1))
```

Comment: thanks a lot it works.